# PowerShell script to run an exe using the Local System Account

Tags: powershell, wix, local-system-account

I am facing an issue with some installation using the Local System Account.

I stumbled upon the following post : 
[Is it possible to execute a custom action in WiX that is a managed .EXE file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932927/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-custom-action-in-wix-that-is-a-managed-exe-file)

The first comment explains my situation accurately - "One other thing to note is that deferred actions run under the context of the system account, so if the exe requires access to a profile for any reason, this will cause it to fail. I had this very issue when trying to generate a certificate as part of my install."

The solution that was suggested was to spawn PowerShell using -RunAs switch and run a script to call the exe.

I have no knowledge of PowerShell. So I need help coming up this script.

Comment: Maybe you can use the built-in [RUNAS](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) utility?

Comment: If you are looking to run something as System then you should look at using PSExec with the -s switch.

Comment: I cannot use the RunAs utitily because I want to execute it using the System account only. Any other pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something as the local system account, the only way I know is to use `psexec -s`. There are some very complicated ways to do it through permanent WMI event consumers but that's way overkill.

Comment: I have tried using that. But my problem is that the exe accesses the profile while installing the certificates, which fails. Check out the link to the question I have posted in my question. Could you suggest me what to do?